# eclipse CDT: searching /usr/lib although not in lib search path

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linker, eclipse-cdt, dynamic-linking

I am trying to run a bit of pcl code (from their website). I am currently, on ubuntu, using boost 1_51 (that I built) and in my Eclipse C++ Build->Settings I have 
`/home/aly/libs/boost_1_51_0/stage/include` in the include path and `/home/aly/libs/boost_1_51_0/stage/lib` in the library search path. I do not have `/usr/include` or `/usr/lib`.

At runtime I am getting some boost error, which made me think perhaps it is not running against the correct libraries as boost_1_46 is built in `/usr/lib` (this is the most up to date version in the ubuntu repos). So I removed a lib file (`libboost_timer.so`) from the `/usr/lib` dir and recompiled (which was fine) and then ran. At runtime I got the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.46.1: cannot open shared object file: N
```

My question is, why if `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` aren't in my include path and library search paths, is my program looking for the 1.46 version?

Additional info:

To compile eclipse is doing:
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker

```
g++ -L/home/aly/libs/OpenCV-2.4.3/release/lib -L/home/aly/libs/boost_1_51_0/stage/lib -o "3DObjectDetection"  ./src/HFNodeSplitCalculator.o ./src/HFNodeUtils.o ./src/HFTreeNode.o ./src/HoughForest.o ./src/ImagePatch.o ./src/Main.o ./src/PatchGenerator.o ./src/utils.o   -lvtkmetaio -lvtkImaging -lvtkIO -lvtkViews -lvtkVolumeRendering -lvtkalglib -lvtkDICOMParser -lvtkInfovis -lvtkFiltering -lvtkGeovis -lGL -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lpcl_io -lpcl_visualization -lpcl_common -lpcl_surface -lpcl_kdtree -lpcl_search -lpcl_geometry -lpcl_features -lvtkproj4 -lvtkParallel -lvtksys -lvtkRendering -lvtkCommon -lboost_serialization -lboost_timer -lpthread -lboost_context -lboost_date_time -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_random -lboost_regex -lglut -lvtkexoIIc -lvtkCharts -lvtkGenericFiltering
Finished building target: 3DObjectDetection
```

And my `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is

```
:/home/aly/libs/boost_1_51_0/stage/lib/:/home/aly/libs/OpenCV-2.4.2/build/lib/:/usr/lib/:/home/aly/libs/cuda-5.0/lib:/home/aly/libs/cuda-5.0/lib64
```

As you can see the boost lib dir appears before `/usr/lib`